# Pandas read csv not separating columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv encoded in utf-8 with a comma as separator but the dataframe is not separating any of the columns.

This is an example of the csv file

19,"Aero Biniza",\N,"","BZS","BINIZA","Mexico","N"

The whole file is available here

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airlines.dat

And this is my code

pd.read_csv(input_csv, encoding='utf-8')

I am probably doing something stupid but grateful if anyone can point it out.

Comment: It is `read_csv`. You are having a missing underscore. When using the former, things work as expected

Comment: Seems to work for me using `read_csv` instead.

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake in question. My code does have underscore but still just reads in without separating. So I am still stuck. Can I ask if you managed to read the data from the linked website in and what was your full code?

Answer (score 1):

CSV need a header to have columns be named by them, looks like the csv in the link does not have that.

In order to read a csv in that doesn't have a header you need to pass param header=None:

df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)

See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)